# Socket.IO connection from React to Nodejs - polling repeatedly

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I'm trying to connect `socket.io` from my `React` frontend to my `Node.js` backend

On the client I set up my socket as follows:

```
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';
import { getToken } from './tokenFetcher';
import store from './store';

const socket = io(`${process.env.API_URL}/`, {
    query: `Authorization=${getToken(store.getState())}`,
});
```

Next on my backend I have the following middleware for auth:

```
const socketAuthMiddleware = (socket, next) => {
   const token = socket.handshake.query.Authorization;
   ....
   if (validToken) return next(); 
}
```

Next, I run the following code on the backend:

```
connections.push(socket);

socketToUserMap[userID] = { socketId: socket.id };

socket.enabled = true;

socket.emit('announcements', {
    message: 'A new user has joined!',
});

console.log(
  ' %s sockets is connected',
  connections.length,
  socket.id,
  'connected'
);
```

I then listen for the event on the client:

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    socket.on('announcements', params => {
        console.log('CONNECTED');
    });
};
```

I am not seeing the logs showing up on the client at all. Instead I am seeing the following requests firing:

[image]

They come back with the following response:

```
96:0{"sid":"3P_8ERxEbU1SVriOAAA7","upgrades":["websocket"],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":5000}
```

and a `200` response code.

My websockets tab looks like this:

[image]

On the server I am seeing the following logs repeat every 2-3 seconds:

```
 1 sockets is connected sd2gdVW_SeZ7y5btAACE connected
socket disconnected
 0 sockets is connected
```

indicating that the socket connected (meaning it made it through my auth middleware), but then gets disconnected quickly after.

I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong - I use the same setup for connecting to the server through my iOS app and that works fine.